# How do I remove NEW MENU from Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 version 4.8.03752. Somehow I managed to create a new menu called NEW MENU. I have checked and checked all of the options but can't see a way to remove it and a Google search does not turn up anything. Does anyone know how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it through the `Tools > Customize` menu option.

[How to: Customize menus and toolbars in Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-customize-menus-and-toolbars-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)